# Rails routes: match to nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I can't seem to get this right.
I want to match a short url to a specific nested route.

I want to do this:

`match "/register" => "/businesses/3/customers/new"`

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [redirect](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection).

```
match "/register" => redirect("/businesses/3/customers/new")
```